# Auto resize columns in TreeListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

I create a tree control:

```
self.tree_cat = wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl(self, -1, style=some-styles)
```

Then I add columns:

```
self.tree_cat.AddColumn("blah")
self.tree_cat.AddColumn("blah")
```

Now how do I make the columns auto-resize when I add elements?

Answer (score 0):

The way you *should* be able do this is to use the `wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin` as a mixin class for the `wx.TreeListCtrl`.

But apparently there's a [bug](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/3459) with it currently.